# group by and merge dict with different keys in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, datetime, group-by, aggregate

I have a list of dictionaries that I want to group by date but before that, I need to merge the values of metric and horizon into a new key (e.g. rmse-1, rmse-2, as keys with values 1, 2, etc.). See desired output.

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
dataset = [{'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
            'extra': 0, 
            'horizon': 1, 
            'metric': 'rmse', 
            'value': 1
           },
           {'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 11, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
            'extra': 0, 
            'horizon': 1, 
            'metric': 'rmse', 
            'value': 2
           },
           {'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
            'extra': 0, 
            'horizon': 2, 
            'metric': 'rmse', 
            'value': 3
           },
           {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 11, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
            'extra': 0, 
            'horizon': 2, 
            'metric': 'rmse', 
            'value': 4
           }     
    ]
```

This is the desired output:

```
desired_output= [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
             'rmse-1': 1,  
             'rmse-2': 3, 
           },
           {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 11, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
             'rmse-1': 2,  
             'rmse-2': 4, 
           }
    ]
```

Here is a partial solution. It requires the group by date but there different keys in each row ...

```
def group_and_merge_dataset(dataset, group_by_key, merge_value_keys):

    new_dataset = []
    for item in dataset:
        item.update({'metric': "{}-{}".format(item['metric'],item['horizon'])})
        d = {'date': item[group_by_key], item['metric']: item['value']}
        new_dataset.append(d)
    
    for item in new_dataset:
        print(item)

print(group_and_merge_dataset(dataset, 'date', ['metric', 'horizon']))
```

output:

```
{'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'rmse-1': 1}
{'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 11, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'rmse-1': 2}
{'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'rmse-2': 3}
{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 11, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'rmse-2': 4}
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Following may not be the final solution; but will help as guidance to achieve your goal.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
dataset = [{'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
            'extra': 0, 
            'horizon': 1, 
            'metric': 'rmse', 
            'value': 1
           },
           {'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 11, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
            'extra': 0, 
            'horizon': 1, 
            'metric': 'rmse', 
            'value': 2
           },
           {'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
            'extra': 0, 
            'horizon': 2, 
            'metric': 'rmse', 
            'value': 3
           },
           {'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 11, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
            'extra': 0, 
            'horizon': 2, 
            'metric': 'rmse', 
            'value': 4
           }     
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)

>>                       date  extra  horizon metric  value
>> 0 2022-09-10 00:00:00+00:00      0        1   rmse      1
>> 1 2022-09-11 00:00:00+00:00      0        1   rmse      2
>> 2 2022-09-10 00:00:00+00:00      0        2   rmse      3
>> 3 2022-09-11 00:00:00+00:00      0        2   rmse      4
```

Join `metric` and `horizon` values:

```py
df["metric_horizon"] = df["metric"] + "-" + df["horizon"].astype(str)

>>                        date  extra  horizon metric  value metric_horizon
>> 0 2022-09-10 00:00:00+00:00      0        1   rmse      1         rmse-1
>> 1 2022-09-11 00:00:00+00:00      0        1   rmse      2         rmse-1
>> 2 2022-09-10 00:00:00+00:00      0        2   rmse      3         rmse-2
>> 3 2022-09-11 00:00:00+00:00      0        2   rmse      4         rmse-2
```

Pivot `metric_horizon` joined values to columns:

```py
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=["date"], columns="metric_horizon", values="value", aggfunc="first").reset_index()

>> metric_horizon                      date  rmse-1  rmse-2
>> 0              2022-09-10 00:00:00+00:00       1       3
>> 1              2022-09-11 00:00:00+00:00       2       4
```

It is almost in your desired format. You can now convert dataframe `df2` to dictionary as required.

Comment: Thank you Azhar, this is a good solution but I need to group dict because using pandas is too slow. Here I have used and example with just two metrics but I actually have 16 metrics.